# Can't get update statement to work with listbox value as variable

Tags: sql, vba, ms-word

I have a listbox that contains a list of names. When you select a name, and click a button it will mark the person as here. The button click calls a sub that is meant to run an update query on the attendance table and change the seated column to true. It should then also move the person's name from the listbox to a second one that just shows who has been marked seated. I keep getting an error and it looks like the variable(agent) is being given a null value, but I can't figure out why.

For clarification: Attendance is the name of a form and Agentname is the name of the listbox.

```vb
Sub markseated()
    Dim itemIndex As Long
    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim Server_Name As String
    Dim Database_Name As String
    Dim SQLStr As String
    Dim agent As Variable
    Set agent = Attendance.Agentname.value
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = Cn.Execute(SQLStr)
    Server_Name = "SDL02-VM25"
    Database_Name = "PIA"
    SQLStr = "Update dbo.[Attendance]Set [Seated] = 'True' Where [AgentName] ='" & agent & "'"
    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & vbNullString
    rs.Open
    Cn.Close
    With Attendance.Agentname
        For itemIndex = .ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If .Selected(itemIndex) Then
                Attendance.Seated.AddItem .list(itemIndex)
                .RemoveItem itemIndex
                Attendance.Agentname.ListIndex = -1
            End If
        Next itemIndex
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Only done a little bit of VBA. First check whether `set agent = Attendance.Agentname.value` is actually doing what you expect.

Comment: That seems to be where the problem is, agent is getting a value of "" for some reason. But I'm not sure how else to set it's value equal to the selected person.

Comment: If I had this  problem, my first fix would be to ensure that the `Variable` datatype can be used for that type of `set` call. My second would be to check that the `set` call is returning anything at all regardless of the datatype I use.

Comment: What's the error, exactly? In VBA I've never heard of dimming anything as datatype `Variable`, is that suppoed to be `Variant`?

Comment: I though variable was correct, but maybe it should be variant. When I try variant it gives me a type mismatch error and says that attendance.agentname.value = null. If the listbox has "John Doe" highlighted when I click the button, I want attendance.agentname.value to be "John Doe". That seems to be where it's breaking, but I don't know how to get it there.

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, then we are looking in the wrong place here. The datatype chosen should have nothing to do with the value of `attendance.agentname.value`. Either the listbox is not functioning as you expect it to, or possibly the `datatype` `Variable` has been set up incorrectly.

Comment: Your `update` statement is missing a space between the table name and the `Set` keyword. Also, consider using an `ADODB.Command` with an `ADODB.Parameter` to pass that value securely, e.g. `SQLStr = "UPDATE dbo.Attendance SET Seated = 'True' WHERE AgentName = ?;"`. That said, Everyone is thoroughly confused over what that `Variable` data type might be. Is `Attendance` the name of a form and `AgentName` the name of the `ListBox` control? If so, consider renaming it `AgentNamesBox` to disambiguate.

Comment: Yes, sorry.  Attendance is the name of a form and Agentname is the name of the listbox control. I'll edit the post to reflect that.